# If value is not in Table A, then select original value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

Let me add more detailed and rephrase my question, since I rushed writing it as I was leaving work:

Firstly the tables:

TABLE A has a 1:1 relationship to TABLE B

TABLE A has a 1:M relationship to TABLE XYZ (the table we want to update)

I have a stored procedure named, sp_parent that calls a different stored procedure named sp_update_child (this so main function is to update a table)

In my sp_update_child I have a variable set like this:

```
SET @trustee_variable_id = SELECT TOP 1 ID_A
                           FROM TABLE A
                           WHERE clause1 AND clause2 AND etc
```

It returns an ID, let's say 3000

Then it goes to the update statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE_XYZ
SET TABLE_XYZ.trustee_id = (@trustee_variable_id = TABLE_XYZ.trustee_id`
```

However, it cannot be updated because the ID retrieved, 3000 from TABLE A, is not in TABLE B and the only way to update that specific column is if ID 3000, is in TABLE B.

How do I add a check to say, if the ID retrieved from TABLE A is not in TABLE B, then update TABLE_XYZ.trustee_id with the original ID that is already in trustee_id column?

Below is my script - not sure if I am heading in the right direction:

```
UPDATE TABLE_XYZ 
SET @trustee_variable_id = CASE 
    WHEN @trustee_variable_id NOT IN (SELECT ID_A FROM TABLE_B)
        THEN (SELECT trustee_id FROM TABLE_XYZ WHERE clause1 = clause2)
```

Can anyone point in the right direction please?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you using an update statement when you aren't updating the table? Usually you would be using a select statement to set a variable.

Comment: @AznDevil92 Hmm, lots of issues with this.  I'll start off by saying that a SQL update statement updates a column in the table.  So do you want to update a column or set the value of a variable?  Variables start with "@", column names do not.  Also, it might help to begin by posting the schemas of tables XYZ, A, and B and some sample data.

Comment: Sorry all for the confusion, I did not fully understand the query myself, since some other DBA wrote it. But hopefully the new question clears any confusion up. Please let me know if there are any more confusion to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely confused by your update statement, but I think you might mean this.

```
update table_xyz
set trustee_id = @trustee_variable_id 
where exists (
  select * from table_b where id_b = @trustee_variable_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic, then....
Table_a and Table_b contains two ids (and maybe other fields).  The one you want to look for, and the one you want to use.  For the sake of your example, the id_a and id_b are the id you wish to look for, and I made a column named return_id which holds the value you want to put in your table you are updating.

I assume table_a might look like the following:
**id_a, return_id**
1, 10
2, 20
4, 40

And table_b might look like this:
**id_b, return_id**
1, 100
2, 200
3, 300
4, 400

Now here is the sql:

```
declare @trustee_variable_id int = 3
select case 
    when 
        not exists  (select return_id from table_a where id_a=@trustee_variable_id ) then
        (select return_id from table_b where id_b=@trustee_variable_id)
    else
        (select return_id from table_a where id_a=@trustee_variable_id)
    end
```

Since 3 does not exist in table_a, it looks to table_b to return the value of 300.

If you run it with `declare @trustee_variable_id int = 2` it will return 20 since 2 exists in table_a

The example SQL above is a select statement, convert it into an update:

```
update [SomeTable] set [SomeColumn] = case 
    when 
        not exists  (select return_id from table_a where id_a=@trustee_variable_id ) then
        (select return_id from table_b where id_b=@trustee_variable_id)
    else
        (select return_id from table_a where id_a=@trustee_variable_id)
    end
```

And don't forget a WHERE clause at the end of your update statement or you will alter ALL rows ;) Unless thats your intention.

Comment: you will have performance issue, suggest not produce lookups for each record,

you can use update from contruction  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: Yes, other methods would be lighter load but are much harder to read (human) and I presume the OP isn't ready for deep sql. ;)  My simplified query satisfies all of his/her requirements stated (including null if not in either table).  And from the way the question was phrased, this appears to be a one-off solution to update a table so long term performance issues would be unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just give you the select statement

```
select isnull(tableB.col, tableA,col) 
  from tableA 
  left join TableB 
    on tableB.col = tableA.col
```